# How do I defeat a Wispmother in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was trying to get to Hrogthar from Whiterun (Go to Iverstead, look for giant stairs, follow them), and I ran into a wispmother.  I had a housecarl with me, but still died when the Wispmother spawned two other Wispmothers to join her.

I'm a level 9 Wood elf specializing in Archery, One-handed Weapons, and Sneaking. What do I need to do to beat her?  Spells? (Which ones?) Regular weapons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She didn't actually spawn more Wispmothers, she spawned shades, which are much weaker (I've never had one last more than 2 hits). I used a flame atronach and lots of fire to take her out the first time, and the second time I wailed on her with an axe. She has a lot of health, but her attacks aren't that dangerous. Just keep healthy and keep kiting, or let your companion draw aggro, and keep laying down the hurt.

Comment: Flame Atronach is a very sexy companion, for every meaning of the word.

Comment: What is recommended if I don't have a flame atronach at my disposal? I only have familiars and they seem useless. Flame is helping, but it's barely making a dent in her health. Given up for now.. might have better luck later.

Comment: I only found Wispmothers much later in the game and even then I had to try twice, but once you know the right approach (Fire! Lot's of Fire!) it's not that hard (at least with a mage at my level ;-)).

Comment: I'm level 13 and the one in Labyrinthian Thoroughfare is totally kicking my butt. Fire doesn't do much of anything. My shout damages her but not by very much. Haven't been able to defeat her yet. She's harder to be than any dragon I've fought yet.

Comment: ha i was much higher then 13 and i was stuggling with the Labyrinthian! i ended up killing her just by running and bowing.

Comment: @Konerak you could say she is very.... *hot*

Comment: and here I am, lv6, trying to fight here in the mountains because a random dragon spawned on me...

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid her completely by going around the mountain (unless you're in the labyrinthian). I accidentally tried to get to the greybeards directly by going up the mountain and kept getting killed by the wispmother. Screw killing her, its almost impossible unless you're level 10 and up. The easy way is to go around the mountain to Ivensgard and then take the 7000 steps from Ivensgard by going around the mountain. It's a long way but it's safer and the more correct way.  If the wispmother is avoidable, load an earlier save or run away and jump down the mountain and travel on the road. It's better and you probably won't run into strong monsters. (except the frost troll.)

Comment: Definitely, and you can also sneak past the frost troll fairly easily by waiting till it takes off after whatever it's fighting and then skirting around to the left.

Man that climb from Ivensgard is loooooong !

Answer (score 2):

Dodge, Duck, Dip, Dive, and Dodge. Literally dodge her tri-freeze attack by moving towards one direction and stopping as soon as she attacks (she anticipated where you'll be so you could just stop but it's better to switch directions). You should keep out of her constant attack within a close range- that kills within 15 seconds.

-As to avoiding her completely, just get a horse. They are monsters at climbing mountain sides. They can climb anything. Just climb straight up to high hrothgar. Animal cruelty? Nah. Just sayin.

Answer (score 1):

I sat behind the rocks in labyrinthian and used flame atronachs and firebolts.  Both were really effective.  With the boss guy I sat up near where the stairs are and he sat there not attacking at all so I killed him in about 6 minutes.  I'm only lvl 26.

The sad thing is I'm level 68 or so enchanting and that's my highest level skill

I also beat Arcifer or what ever his name is easily because his own magic anomaly came at me from the front and he tried to attack me. Then the anomaly attacked him.  4 fire balls and a anomaly rule.

When you're the Archmage anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can defeat her easily. I'm level 13, and I did it by using Firebolt and Flame Attronach (and some running away skills!) It took a while but its possible!

Answer (score -1):

Well, I was just in the Labrynthian. All I used was an elven bow with soul trap enchanted on it and orcish arrows combined with firebolt. Seemed to work well for me.

Answer (score -1):

I found an easy way to kill her if you are doing mission labrynthian.

1. Get her to follow you to stairs and run around behind the wall were the gate window openings are. Don't let her follow you around there though
2. Move behind the rocks to the left then back in front of window and use flames
3. Don't let her hit you back, she still can though the window