# I'm not powerful enough to continue the main quest(s). What can I do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It's seems I've hit a bump: Every time I try to battle something I die. I couldn't go to High Hrothgar because I couldn't beat the troll. So I figured I'd become a Stormcloak and head over to Windhelm and maybe level up on my journey there. So I leave Ivarstead, die to a bear, and end up fast traveling to Whiterun. I start off on the trail leading to Windhelm and die to a Frostbite Spider.

I'm a level 6 Breton. I have light armor and I am focused on 1H weps (mainly sword) and destruction magic (and a little alteration, but not til later in the game). Am I just advancing in the story line to quickly, or do I have a bad character build?

Comment: Why bother focusing on the main quest right now? There are hundreds of other things to do in Skyrim, most of which will help advance your level to prepare you for the main quest line. Join the companions, do some random quests for the Jarls or inn keepers, etc.

Comment: @spugsley The reason I wanted to do this part was because it said to talk with the greybeards immidiately and I wanted anxious to learn about about my new found powers. Also does being in the companions affect my relationship with the imperials/stormcloaks?

Comment: @JonnyB I've found no impact on your stance in the civil war if you join the Companions. They aren't really allied to either side.

Comment: You can usually lose the troll in the rocks, thats how I got around that particular thing at like lvl 10 or so.

Comment: At level 6, you are still too small.  The main game should be doable at level 20+ without any problems.

Comment: I got to the Greybeards at level 6. The first troll I could go around him walking over his cave. The second troll I came up to him, screamed and then use my sprint to run away from him.

Comment: And use carriages in the early game - if you have the gold to avoid all of that walking - doesn't help you get to places like kynesgrove but it should be good enough. Also get a follower - quickly. Even Lydia (the Housecarl in Whiterun) is good enough to take out a bear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bears are tough. A few tips: try upgrading your equipment if you have smithing, and either dual-wield swords (if that's your weapon of choice) and attack with both (both mouse buttons simultaneously on PD) or use a sword and a shield.

It's possible that it's just too early to do what you're trying to do. Level up a bit further before trying to progress the main storyline. Do a few side quests, get better weapons and armor, get a few perks in light armor and one-handed weapons.

Don't forget to bring potions!

Comment: Is the barrow ivarstead good to train at?

Answer (score 3):

The same thing happened to me the [first time I tried to go to High Hrothgar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36180/how-do-i-defeat-a-wispmother-in-skyrim).  Really, you're at the point where you can either:

1. Buy a horse for 1000 gold (not easy at your level) and try to sprint up to High Hrothgar with it, or
2. Go do something else for a while.  For me, I completed the College of Winterhold questline, and when I was done with it, I was level 13 or so, and at that point was able to make it to the top of High Hrothgar without dying.

The Main quest will always be there; and it levels up with you (the actual quest itself, not traveling to and fro), so you need not worry about completing it right now: You can always do other questlines for a few dozen levels (but don't wait until level 50 to do the main quest, because you'll find that it stops leveling up with you at that point).

Comment: Stealth & Darkness, two great tastes that go great together.  An Arrow hitting the rock behind him will encourage him to be looking the wrong way.  Also, leaving the path and going around the rocks to the left isn't difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Try gaining a few levels in smithing and alchemy. Both will pay them self really quick trough selling potion (Keep mana and health potions!) and weapons/armors. 
Investing a few perk points in smithing will grant you a huge advantage equipment wise.

This should also grant you a few level if you do it long enough ;)

Getting a companion (for example the mercenary in Whiterun) to tank some damage may help too.

Answer (score 2):

Just run past. I did this at level 4. Good rewards at the top, too . . .

Answer (score 1):

I have started the game in novice difficulty and I noticed it is really easy. You can change the difficulty in the game whenever you feel it's necessary.

Comment: Isn't the game incredibly boring when you make it that easy?

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop: Novice is a setting from the game not from me. I could use a trainer. It's like I'm cautious person and the game is thrilling me.

Comment: I understand it's a difficulty setting in Skyrim. I'm saying, setting the difficulty that low takes all of the challenge out of the game. You might as well hack yourself a pair of instant-kill weapons and invincibility armor.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop: I didn't do the game and it is advertise in the loading screen. They say you can change the difficulty level but I'm not a hardcore gamer more a casual gamer.

Comment: This answer is not helpful. Being at Novice and lvl 6 doesn't alleviate the problem.

Comment: @rlb.usa: I wasn't exactly lvl 6 when I climbed that mountain but I provided a legit solution. You should be more specific about your downvote and comment.

Comment: Changing the difficulty to the lowest setting doesn't remove the problem of the Snow Troll appearing, and at a low level, he will still one-shot you if he gets a hit in.

Comment: That ruins the fun of it then... I like a challenge!

Answer (score 1):

You are far too low level to climb to High Hrothgar. Just find some sidequests that seem interesting. There are tons. Talk to people and ask for work. The Jarl or his majordomo will typically send you on a random bandit-killing mission. On the way, go to every undiscovered symbol that pops up on your compass. Enter and explore.

Since you are already in Ivarstead, talk to an innkeep. I think they will ask you to check out the barrow, which they believe to be haunted. It was a pretty neat little dungeon, suitable for low level, iirc.

Answer (score 1):

When I went to High Hrothgar I couldn't beat the troll either as the first time you go up it is pretty early in the game.  I just ran past the troll.  Lydia was with me and she helped to distract it and eventually she came back to me.  I am level 32 and I have not killed a Frost Troll yet.  They are tough.  I got stuck of the Thalmor Embassy quest so I am just waiting and I upped my Smithing to 100 and got the best armor possible for this moment.

Comment: "Stuck on" or "sick of?"

Answer (score 1):

Killing Frost Trolls should be easy, I did it at level 5. But if you're on a low level, try to level up only from combat, otherwise the monsters will get tougher and you'll still be weak. And if all else fails, just run past the monsters. And a nice quest to do is Mind of a Madman. It's easy, and doesn't involve too much fighting. If you're tired of walking places, take the carriage, that's what I always do. Also see what perks you choose, many times that affects how week you fight. Focus on one subject. Start with, I dunno, Destruction, or whatever you like, that way you get better through practice and perks. I recommend also to not waste level ups on Stamina, Health and Magicka are much more important. Another easy way to become better is to clear out every bandit camp or cave you walk by, that helps a lot. Good Luck! :)

Comment: If nothing works, make a new person.

Answer (score 0):

Just lure your little troll friend over toward the edge, and then, throw him off with an unrelenting force. FUS RO DAH!

Comment: Except you don't have `FUS RO DAH` yet when you're ascending the 7000 steps, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Huh? Too low a level to complete the quest? Nonsense! I just finished it at level 4. As long as you can kill the wolves along the way, you'll be fine.

You don't have to shy away from it because of Snow Trolls. Remember, you don't have to (and can't, at this level) kill every single thing that you encounter.

**Instead, just run away.** Take as wide a path around it as you can manage, use sneak as much as you can. When you're spotted, stop sneaking, put away your weapon (for faster running), and then run away. He can't keep up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get to wind helm or any city go to whiterun stables and ask some dude on a carriage to transport you. It is very cheap (abt 20-50 septims)

Answer (score 0):

Steal a horse at night and ride it pass all the enemies on the way up.  Just don't get caught stealing :)

Answer (score -1):

Try kiting your enemies into a nearby town and let the guards deal with them.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question...